# Por qué NO genera todos los colores hexadecimales?

Tags: javascript, color

Hice un código con el fin de generar **TODOS** los colores `hexadecimales`, el problema es que solo me genera aproximadamente `4.000` entradas, en vez de las `16.777.216` esperadas

```js
function paleta(toreturn = []) { //
    var poss = "0123456789ABCDEF",
        comb = "";
    for (var i = 0, max = poss.length; i < 16777216 * 6; i++) { // 16,777,216 * 6 , ya que cada color necesita 6 iteraciones
        let random = poss[Math.floor(Math.random() * max)]; // letra o numero aleatorio
        comb += random; // concateno la letra o numero que se ha formado aleatoriamente
        if (comb.length === 6 && !toreturn.includes(comb)) { // si el color ya tiene sus 6 digitos y además el color no está en el array
            toreturn.push("#" + comb); // introduzco el color al array
            comb = ""; // y vacio nuevamente para formar OTRO color
        }
        if (comb.length === 6 && toreturn.includes(comb)) i -= 6;
        /* En este if, si el color YA se ha formado y a su vez YA estaba en el array
           de los colores, entonces resto 6 a i , para que todas las iteraciones
           con las que se formó ese color, no se pierdan, ya que ese color YA ESTABA. */
    }
    return toreturn; // retorno el array
}
console.log(paleta().length) // Aprox: 4000 colores
```

Comment: Yo creo que es porque en cada iteración no se da un número único, sino que en algunos casos el aleatorio que se genera se repite. 
¿No sería más fácil ir en orden y convertir a hexadecimal? Así se garantizan todos los colores.

Comment: la comprobación se realiza si el número ya estaba en el array y a la vez se resta 6 para no perder las iteraciones.

Comment: Es difícil predecir el comportamiento o hacer prueba de escritorio con ese llamado aleatorio. Sin embargo, en aras de resolver tu problema de todos los colores, te dejo este fragmento `var colors = new Array();
for(col=0x0;col<=0xFFFFFF;col++) {
  colors.push("#" + col);
}` Que llena el arreglo con todos los colores. [referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503286/iterate-through-colors-in-javascript)

Comment: nisiquiera genera colores.

Comment: este código no sirve para generar todos los colores, es para generar colores aleatorios sin repetición en un ciclo de **16777216 * 6** iteraciones. En el mejor de los casos (casi implosible) generaria todos los colores en el espectro pero ¿Cuál es la probabilidad de que eso suceda? Cercana a cero

Comment: una pregunta eduardo  la cantidad de colores que te brinda siempre es  apx 4000 colores o  en ocaciones te da mas 4000 colores

Comment: Siempre aprox 4000 esteban

Comment: Por qué rene? debería entregarme todos los colores, por qué aún siendo aleatoria, cuando el color ya esta repetido, primero no lo vuelvo a introducir como color válido y además, resto las 6 iteraciones para no perder esas iteraciones usadas.

Comment: Pero no vacías `comb`. Por lo tanto en la siguiente iteración a `comb` le añades un nuevo dígito y tiene una longitud de 7 (que no cumple ninguna de las dos condiciones), en la siguiente tiene una longitud de 8, luego 9, 10, 11.... hasta que sale del bucle sin añadir ningún color más.

Comment: @Eduardo El hecho de que no hayas asignado la recompensa, sin siquiera seguir las respuestas que recibiste, sin indicar en comentarios si alguna estaba bien, o ayudando a orientar hacía lo que te interesaba, y que aún no hayas aceptado una respuesta, me parecen una falta de respeto a quienes invirtieron tiempo intentando ayudarte

Comment: @Mariano, pretendo darme el tiempo para revisar estas respuestas, ya que me gusta entenderlo bien y hay varios conceptos que aún no conozco en las respuestas, por eso necesito tiempo , y precisamente este último tiempo no he tenido nada de aquel, por eso es que no he comentado casi nada, pronto lo veré

Answer (score 8):

Basándome en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16503514/3866134), mi idea, (para que el navegador no quede "congelado") te propongo usar un `generator` junto con `setInterval`. La utilidad de setInterval es que no ejecutará la próxima llamada mientras que haya un código actualmente corriendo.

```js
const iter = paleta()
const intervalId = setInterval(log, 0)

function * paleta() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 16777216; ++i) {
      yield '#' + ('00000' + i.toString(16)).slice(-6)
  }
}

function log() {
  const next = iter.next()
  const { done, value } = next
  console.log(value)
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = value
  if(done) {
    clearInterval(intervalId)
  }
}
```

Esta idea también se puede aplicar a tú código:

```js
const iter = paleta()
const intervalId = setInterval(log, 0)

function * paleta() {
  var poss = '0123456789ABCDEF',
      comb = '', l = poss.length,
      toreturn = new Set();
  for (var i = 0, max = l; i < 16777216 * 6; i++){
    let random = poss[Math.floor(Math.random() * max)];
    comb += random; 
    
    if (comb.length === 6 && !toreturn.has(comb)) {
      toreturn.add(comb);
      yield '#' + comb;
      comb = ''; 
    }
    if (comb.length === 6 && toreturn.has(comb)){
      i -= 6;
      comb = '';
    }
  }
}

function log() {
  const next = iter.next()
  const { done, value } = next
  console.log(value)
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = value
  if(done) {
    clearInterval(intervalId)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

El problema es que cuando una combinación ya está incluida sí descuentas 6 del contador del bucle, pero no vacías la variable `comb`. Por lo tanto en la siguiente iteración se le añade un nuevo dígito hexadecimal a `comb` con lo que tendrá una longitud de 7 (que no cumple ninguna de las dos condiciones), la siguiente iteración 8, la siguiente 9,.... hasta que sale del bucle.

Por lo tanto una vez que se repite un color ya se va creando un valor de `comb` cada vez más largo hasta que finaliza el bucle.

Si vacías la variable `comb` cuando el color ya existe te acabará generando todos (si tienes la paciencia para esperar a que acabe el código). Cuantos más colores existan en el array más posibilidad habrá de que se generen repetidos por lo que más se tardará en encontrar uno nuevo para añadir. Para los últimos puede llevar muchísimo tiempo.

Si lo que quieres es crear una paleta con todos los colores ordenados de manera aleatoria, es mejor opción crear un array con todos los valores y después ordenarlo de manera aleatoria.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo en el que creo un array con todos los valores y después lo ordeno de forma aleatoria, aprovechando el mismo proceso de ordenación para transformar el valor numérico en una cadena con el código del color.

Después sí que utilizo jQuery para mostrar los 500 primeros colores del array. No muestro los casi 17 millones de colores posibles para no bloquear el navegador:

```js
// Crea un array con todos los números desde 0 hasta 0xFFFFFF 
for(var paleta=[], i=0; paleta.length<0x1000000; paleta.push(i++));
// Ordena el array de forma aleatoria traduciendo los números a 
paleta = paleta.map((e, i, a) => {
  // Calcula un índice aleatorio entre el actual y el final
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (a.length - i)) + i;
  // Calcula el color para el número de la posición aleatoria
  var color = '#' + ('000000' + a[randomIndex].toString(16)).slice(-6);
  // Almacena el valor actual en la posición aleatoria
  a[randomIndex] = e;
  // Devuelve el color calculado
  return color;
});


// Dibuja los 500 primeros elementos de la paleta
$(function(){
  var $paleta = $('#paleta');
  for(var i=0; i<500; i++){
      var $color = $('<div>');
      $color.css('background-color', paleta[i]);
      $color.text(paleta[i]);
      $paleta.append($color);
  }
});
```

```css
#paleta div{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="paleta"></div>
```

Comment: Lo intenté y no obtuve ningún cambio, de hecho si no resto las 6 iteraciones obtengo aprox la misma cantidad

Comment: Claro, porque según tu código, una vez que encuentra un color existente ya no vuelve a añadir ningún color nuevo al resultado, por lo que lo que hagas a partir de ahí no influye en el resultado final

Answer (score 5):

Alternativamente, podrías usar la paleta que ofrece cada navegador en un [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/color):

```js
document.getElementById('input-color')
  .addEventListener('input',
    function(e) {
      let colorSeleccionado =  e.target.value;
      console.log('Color:', colorSeleccionado);
    }
  );
```

```html
<input type="color" id="input-color" value="#ee4444">
```

> Actualmente no funciona en [algunos navegadores](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color).

Answer (score 4):

Otra posible solución es usar [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) o [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame)

Dejo un ejemplo mostrando `setInterval` vs `requestAnimationFrame`.

```js
// Request Animation Frame
getColorRAF(0x0);

// Set Interval
getColorInt();

//

function getColorRAF(color) {
  var rgb = '#' + ('00000' + color.toString(16)).slice(-6);
  document.getElementById('rafLog').value = rgb;
  document.getElementById('raf').style.backgroundColor = rgb;
  if (color <= 0xFFFFFF) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      getColorRAF(color + 1);
    });
  }
}

function getColorInt() {
  var color = 0x0;
  var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    var rgb = '#' + ('00000' + color.toString(16)).slice(-6);
    document.getElementById('intLog').value = rgb;
    document.getElementById('int').style.backgroundColor = rgb;
    color += 1;
    if (color > 0xFFFFFF) {
      window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
div,
input,
span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

input,
span {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<span>rAF</span>
<span>setInterval</span>
<br>
<div id="raf"></div>
<div id="int"></div>
<br>
<input id="rafLog">
<input id="intLog">
```

Comment: También lo pensé. Para este caso no creo que haya mucha ganancia respecto a setInterval, pero en el caso de animaciones tengo entendido que es mejor. Buena respuesta!

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo, tu comentario me llevo a actualizar mi respuesta. Gracias!

Comment: El mejor ejemplo, junto con el de Asier! Lástima que no pueda votaros más! PD: Parece más rápido setInterval. Al menos en mi pc.

Comment: Para los que vean que uno corre más rápido que el otro, este artículo describe algunos de los muchos beneficios de usar eficientemente los recursos en animaciones: [*Animating with javascript: from setInterval to requestAnimationFrame*](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/)

Answer (score 3):

Hay varios problemas en el código, pero el fundamental es tratar de ponerlo todo en un solo loop o una función, eso lo hace propenso a tener bugs y hace mas difícil encontrarlos. Uno de los principios del buen código es la modularización.

Debo agregar que la seleccion aleatoria es una forma poco eficiente de generar las combinaciones, ya que al aumentar las combinaciones en el arreglo aumenta la probabilidad de que la combinación generada  se repita, y como se revierte el proceso en cada ciclo fallido, el tiempo de ejecución crece exponencialmente.

Aqui una solucion recursiva que es mas facil de comprender y mas eficiente:

```
//en cada iteracion paso el arreglo con combinaciones de a n, 
//empezando con 1
function paleta(current) { //

        var result=[];
        //caso base, cada string independiente tiene longitud de 6
        if (current.length>0 && current[0].length==6){
            return current;
        }
        // en otro caso agregamos cada letra a cada arreglo de 
        //recursion pasada
        var poss = "0123456789ABCDEF"; 
        for (var j = 0;j<current.length;j++){
            for (var i=0;i<poss.length;i++){
                var tem=current[j]+poss[i];
                result.push(tem);
            }
        }
        return paleta(result);            
    }

//nota que aqui hice un cambio para no comenzar con array vacio
console.log(paleta("0123456789ABCDEF".split("")).length);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0mt8xod/2/)

---

**Suponiendo** que quieras continuar con el otro enfoque recomiendo que se creen 2 ciclos, uno que controle el numero de combinaciones generadas y otro que controle el numero de letras en cada combinación. También propongo que el código para la generación de cada combinación se coloque en una función aparte.
   Para asegurarte de que en cada ciclo se realice la inserción de un nuevo elemento debes colocar un bloque de código como este dentro del for:
    while combinacion_en_arreglo():
        generar_combinacion()
    agregar_combinacion()

El resultado de mis recomendaciones quedaria asi:

```
 function paleta(toreturn = []) { //
    var poss = "0123456789ABCDEF",
    var comb = "";
    while(toreturn.length!=16777216){ 
        comb=genera(poss);
        if(!toreturn.includes(comb)){
            toreturn.push(comb);
        }
    }
    return toreturn; // retorno el array
}
function genera(poss){
    var comb="";

    for (var j = 0;j<6;j++){
        var ind=Math.floor(Math.random()*15);  
        comb+=poss[ind];
    }
    return comb;
}
```

**Repito, esta solución es muy poco eficiente, yo me decantaría por la forma recursiva.**

**BONUS**

Hay una solución mucho mas simple, no se porque no lo habia pensado:

```
var tem=[];
for(var i =0;i<16777216;i++){
    var hx=i.toString(16);      
    tem.push(hx);
}
```

Lo que hace este algoritmo es simplemente ir contando hasta el numero de combinaciones posibles, cada numero lo convierte a hexadecimal usando toString(16) y lo agrega a la lista. Un problema que te podria generar es que los numeros no tienen padding a la izquierda del positivo mas significativo.

Comment: El primer código, no realiza más de 200k de colores y el segundo hasta 3k, además te equivocas en lo del número aleatorio, el 0 es inclusivo por lo cual genera números del 0-15 multiplicando por 16

Comment: Sobre el numero aleatorio: cierto, fue una confusión con las variables del for, ahora lo edito. Sobre la versión recursiva ya hice la prueba y si genera el numero de combinaciones que se piden.

Comment: También  probé que todas las combinaciones sean diferentes usando new Set().

Answer (score 3):

Se que no es lo que estas pidiendo, pero a mi me genera cierto conflicto el estar generando números al azar para formar la paleta de colores, es por eso que me di a la tarea de generar un código que te obtenga todas las combinaciones posibles:

**Código**

```js
var array_hex = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"];
var paleta_colores=[];
var cont_array=0;
var cont_colores=1;


for (var h1 = 0; h1 < array_hex.length; h1++) {
 for (var h2 = 0; h2 < array_hex.length; h2++) {
  for (var h3 = 0; h3 < array_hex.length; h3++) {
   for (var h4 = 0; h4 < array_hex.length; h4++) {
    for (var h5 = 0; h5 < array_hex.length; h5++) {
     for (var h6 = 0; h6 < array_hex.length; h6++) {
      paleta_colores.push("#"+array_hex[h1]+array_hex[h2]+array_hex[h3]+array_hex[h4]+array_hex[h5]+array_hex[h6]);
      console.log("Color:"+paleta_colores[cont_array]+" Contador de colores: "+cont_colores);
      cont_array++;
      cont_colores++;
 
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

Se me hace algo mas sencillo y cumple el propósito de generarte todas las combinaciones posibles de colores hexadecimales, prácticamente solo trabajas con iteraciones. Espero te sirva y ayude en lo que tratas de hacer.

**Nota:** Perdón por el desorden en la sintaxis, fue algo rápido.

Comment: por que puede utilizar la respuesta de ferney y si lo necesitas aleatorio podría guardar todas las combinaciones en una lista   y  con un random sacar la posición de la lista  y eliminar el numero del color  y repetir el proceso y asi con todos los colores

Comment: No comprendí el comentario después de lo aleatorio, si es una respuesta para mi o comentario acerca de la pregunta que se planteo

Comment: es un aclaracion de como se podria utilizar el código  que tiene para la solución  seria guardas todas la combinaciones  en una lista y por medio de un random ir sacando  colores al azar  de la lista  y el color removerlo de la lista y realizar el proceso hasta que la lista este vacía   para que tenga asi todo los colores de forma aleatoria

Comment: A o.k ya entendí @estebanfabianpatiño, si,  puede unir el código que compartí con lo que tiene y optimizar la función que quiere realizar con los colores hexadecimal, si mi código les fue útil, no se olviden votar.

Comment: Tú código me cerró el navegador

Comment: El código te genera más de 1850000 combinaciones, hasta allí me quede ayer después de un rato. Al ser muchas es posible que se ponga lento el navegador, yo lo probé con sublime text 3, pero te puedo garantizar que obtendrás toda la paleta de colores, de eso no hay duda.

Answer (score 1):

Como respuesta a tu pregunta, debo decir que NO se generan todos los colores simplemente porque ese codigo solo genera valores aleatorios y no TODOS los colores. Si quieres que tu codigo lo haga, simplemente puedes hacer 6 ciclos for anidados donde cada uno se refiera a uno de los digitos hexadecimales y formar los colores. Si lo que quieres es que aparezcan en orden aleatorio, solamente tienes que generarlos todos y luego comenzar a intercambiar posiciones de forma aleatoria.

Answer (score 1):

En las iteraciones del ciclo cuando  `comb.length === 6 && toreturn.includes(comb)`  restas 6 a i para volver a empezar a generar el color pero no inicializas `comb comb='`' por lo que en la siguiente iteración se ejecuta `comb += random` y  **`comb.length` sera 7**
a partir de ese momento `comb.length` ira en aumento y ya no se generaran mas códigos de colores ya que `comb.length` **siempre sera mayor que 6**.

Al cambiar `if (comb.length === 6 && toreturn.includes(comb)) { i -= 6;}` por `if (comb.length === 6 && toreturn.includes(comb)) { i -= 6;comb='';}` en teoria tu codigo debe de funcionar sin embargo el numero de iteraciones es aleatorio y exagerado debido a que mientras mas elementos tenga `toreturn` mas difícil es generar un código que no se encuentre.

Por ejemplo  si faltara un solo color al array podría cumplirse esta condición `if (comb.length === 6 && toreturn.includes(comb))` casi infinitamente ya que la probabilidad de que no se repita es de 1 / 16777216. la penúltima es de 2 / 16777216 y así sucesivamente.

Aquí te dejo una opción de código para generar la paleta de colores:

```
function colorPart(i) {

  var c = i.toString(16); 

    if (i < 16) {

      c = '0' + c;
    }

  return c;
}

function getColor (rojo,verde,azul) {

  return '#' + colorPart(rojo) + colorPart(verde) + colorPart(azul);
}

function paleta () {

  var colors = [];
  var rojo;
  var verde;
  var azul;
  for(rojo = 0 ; rojo < 256 ; rojo++ ) {

    for(verde = 0 ; verde < 256; verde++ ) {

      for(azul = 0 ; azul < 256; azul++ ) {


        colors.push(getColor(rojo,verde,azul));
        //console.log(getColor(rojo,verde,azul));
      }

    }
  }
  return colors;
}
```

En una sola función podría quedarte así:

```
function paleta () {

  var colors = [];
  var rojo;
  var verde;
  var azul;
  var a = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

    c = i.toString(16); 

    if (i < 16) {

      c = '0' + c;
    }

    a.push(c);
  }

  for(rojo = 0 ; rojo < 256 ; rojo++ ) {

    for(verde = 0 ; verde < 256; verde++ ) {

      for(azul = 0 ; azul < 256; azul++ ) {


        colors.push('#' + a[rojo] + a[verde] + a[azul]);
      }

    }
  }
  return colors;
}
```

Para ahorrar memoria puede quedar asi:

```
function paleta () {

  var colors = [];
  var rojo,verde,azul,cverde,cazul,ccolor;


  for(rojo = 0 ; rojo < 256 ; rojo++ ) {

    crojo = (rojo < 16) ? '0' : '';
    crojo += rojo.toString(16);


    for(verde = 0 ; verde < 256; verde++ ) {

      cverde = (verde < 16) ? '0' : '';
      cverde += verde.toString(16);

      for(azul = 0 ; azul < 256; azul++ ) {

        cazul = (azul < 16) ? '0' : '';
        cazul += azul.toString(16);

        colors.push('#' + crojo + cverde + cazul);


      }

    }
  }
  return colors;
}
```

Una opción mas sencilla seria (el orden de los colores es diferente en esta funcion):

```
function paleta() {

  var colors = [];
  var color;
  for ( i = 0; i < 16777216 ; i++) {


    color = String("000000" + i.toString(16)).slice(-6);
    colors.push('#' + color);
  }

  return colors;
}


console.log(paleta().length); //16777216
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a realizar el `for`, pero en lugar de sacar los números aleatorios, que nunca vas a obtener todos, haz una **conversión de entero a hexadecimal** en `javascript`.

El problema de los aleatorios, es que hay un momento en el que la secuencia se repite y no vas a conseguir todos los hexadecimales

El código podría ser:

```
comb = "";
    ceros=""
    for(var i=0; i<16; i++){
         comb = (i).toString(16);
         ceros="";
         for (var j=0; j<(6-comb.length);j++){
            ceros=ceros +"0";
         }

         comb= "#" + ceros + comb
         alert(comb)
    }
```